# What is the proper inter-UIViewController relationship so that show() does not present modally?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` (**BaseViewController**) that has one child `UIViewController` (**OneViewController**). OneViewController itself has two child `UIViewControllers` (**OneAViewController** and **OneBViewController**).

When OneAViewController is in view, I want to show OneBViewController using `show(_:sender:)` in a non-modal style. From how I understand it, the `show(_:sender:)` method will not present modally if there is a "proper" relationship between the presenting view controller and the presented view controller. Is this relationship concerning the view hierarchy or the parent-child hierarchy? And who is showing who? Is the parent (OneViewController) showing OneB or is OneA showing its sibling (OneB)? Or must OneB be a child of OneA?

Comment: If `OneAViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController` then a "show" segue will present `OneBViewController` in the navigation stack, otherwise it will be presented modally.   I don't know what other sort of presentation you want.

Comment: I believe it is possible to non-modally present a UIViewController using show(_:sender:) outside of a split-view container controller and a navigation controller, but I could be wrong, although I think this is possible.

Comment: What do you mean "non-modally"?

Comment: Non-modally where it doesn't use a presentation layer that temporarily hides the entire view hierarchy. When you present modally, the presented view controller goes full screen (where you can't even tuck it behind a tab bar). If you capture the view hierarchy in the view debugger on a modal presentation, every view layer is hidden except for the UIWindow and the presented view controller (and the presentation layer), until it's dismissed.

Comment: You can use a modal presentation where the presenting view controller is still visible, but the user can't interact with it or you can use a pop-over presentation style (which is non-modal since the user can still interact with the current view controller).  A non-modal, non-popover presentation is something you would need to do yourself, say using a container view.